# Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I am getting below error when trying to open another https site (with self signed certificate) in IE11.

> "Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security
>   certificate. For more information, see “About Certificate Errors” in
>   Internet Explorer Help."

When using IE9 or IE8, we used to get the same error along with a pop-up message "Show Content" clicking on which will display the content. But IE 11 is not displaying "Show Content" option.

Can you please help in enabling that option for IE11? I researched in SO and lot of other places. The option given was to install the certificate. Is there a way to enable "Show Content" option without going through certificate installation path?

Comment: Refer this link http://esupport.trendmicro.com/solution/en-US/1103987.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot. There is no way to get rid of it without installing the certificate.